# Noble Gas Ionization by Enzymes

Tags: biology, xenobiology

I am simply wondering if an organism could possess an enzyme that could ionize a noble gas such as argon, krypton, or xenon. I was thinking that the organism could obtain energy through light or maybe another way. The main question is: could an enzyme ionize a noble gas or possibly even synthesize compounds that contain noble gases?

Comment: To what purpose? Enzymes can do everything chemists can do, and chemists *can* synthesize quite a few [noble gas compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_gas_compound). They have yet to find a practical use.

Comment: One possible use might be to grab radio-isotopes and immobilize them. If you could encase Radon atoms in bucky-balls (from the link @AlexP provied) you might be able to make a solid out of them. This could be useful for some experimental purposes. Hmm, now that I think of it that might be medically relevant also.

Comment: To the OP, maybe change this to something about what might be the uses of forcing noble gases into a molecule?

Comment: "_I was thinking that the organism could obtain energy through light_" if you were thinking of a neon light powered organism, there's no way you'd get enough energy out to justify the energy expended on getting the stuff to glow in the first place.

Comment: The purpose is very important here. All noble gas compounds are strong oxidizing agents, and most are quite unstable. If a creature's biochemistry asks for a compound like xenon difluoride for its cell function then yes, why not. But storing this kind of compound for later use would be very problematic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ionize, no; synthesize, yes.

Noble gases are perfect. In chemistry terms, they have enough protons to draw electrons to form the perfect valence shell. The way ions are formed is by atoms dumping or drawing electrons to form perfect valence shells. But, since Noble Gases already have perfect shells, they do not form stable ions. Chlorine, which requires one electron to fill it's valence shell does form a stable ion, and Sodium, which donates one electron to drop a shell forms a stable ion, but noble gases have no perfect shell to aspire to because they already have one. It can be ionized, but in order to turn an atom to it's ionic form, one needs to overcome the ionization energy, of which the Noble Gases have the straight-up highest, and will immediately react to the nearest not ionized Noble Gas because of how much it doesn't want to be in that configuration. You'll have the best luck with the more reactive ones, like Xenon and Radon. Oganesson (technically a noble gas, albeit an artificial one) isn't at all, because only five atoms of it have ever been synthesized and it's got a half-life of less than a millisecond.

Synthesis is possible, though has high energy costs, and as pointed out by AlexP, just aren't very useful. I'm not sure what this has to do with light. I *suppose* it might be useful as a high-energy storage system which can handle more energy in a more compact manner than ATP but there's not really a good reason why that would naturally develop, and there are easier ways to do it.